# heroku commands broken after installation of Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby

I tried to run a heroku console for a Rails 3.2 app using

```
heroku run bundle exec rails console
```

a command which has previously worked. It gave me the error message below. I also tried to run

```
heroku info
```

and got a similar error message. I did this both before and after signing in with the heroku toolbelt, same result. I also tried this on another website and got the same result. Both websites are actually working, just can't access the console

Can anyone explain what the problem might be.

!    Heroku client internal error.

```
Error:       No such file or directory -  git --version  (Errno::ENOENT)
Backtrace:   /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:103:in ``'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:103:in `has_git?'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:108:in `git'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:206:in `git_remotes'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:179:in `extract_app_in_dir'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:31:in `app'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:108:in `block in run_attached'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:236:in `action'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:107:in `run_attached'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:21:in `index'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             /usr/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku run bundle exec rails console
Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.33.2 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

Comment: just go heroku console, that works for me and are you inside the base application folder dir?

Comment: heroku console doesn't work either, and yes I'm inside the base folder

Comment: do git --version and see what happens, it seems like heroku is having problem finding git.

Comment: @Guy you're right. -bash: git: command not found .Does this mean git's been uninstalled somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This problem resulted from the installation of Mountain Lion on my Mac. To fix it, I had to open XCode preferences and to install the command line tools in the downloads folder.

Comment: Sometimes that happens :-)